# Can a newly allocated object have previously used ObjectIdentifier in Swift?

Tags: swift, memory

I wonder, if a newly allocated object can have previously used `ObjectIdentifier` (which is basically inferred from a memory address I'd assume).

I'm having this simple implementation of associated objects, and wonder if this could mess things up.

If a new object can, actually, have a previously used address, I wonder how can we know that something is deallocated and clean up existing associations.

```
private var associatedObjects: [String:Any] = [:]

func setAssociatedObject<T>(_ object: AnyObject, name: String, value: T) {
    associatedObjects[associatedObjectKey(object, name: name)] = value
}

func getAssociatedObject<T>(_ object: AnyObject, name: String) -> T? {
    return associatedObjects[associatedObjectKey(object, name: name)] as? T
}

private func associatedObjectKey(_ object: AnyObject, name: String) -> String {
    return "\(ObjectIdentifier(object).hashValue)-\(name)"
}
```

Comment: Not only can `ObjectIdentifier` values be 're-used' after the deallocation of the object they identified (as, like you say, they are based solely on the memory address), but it's possible for the `hashValue` of two different `ObjectIdentifier`s to be the same. If you're on an Apple platform (i.e have ObjC interop), I would advise using Obj-C associated objects instead of trying to roll your own, as the Obj-C runtime takes care of automatically releasing the associated objects upon the deallocation of the object they were associated to.

Comment: You can even prove the 're-usability' of `ObjectIdentifier` yourself by seeing if the following program terminates: `class C {}; let id = ObjectIdentifier(C()); while id != ObjectIdentifier(C()) {}` :)

Comment: Terminates without a single loop iteration, great catch @Hamish !

Comment: I don't think this would be true though: "it's possible for the hashValue of two different ObjectIdentifiers to be the same". hasValue is basically dec view of hex memory address. If they are different - their hashes would not be the same. Or please provide an example and that would be double score for you @Hamish :)

Comment: @Hamish Any idea how to know when object (or it's ObjectIdentifier) when deallocated for any objects that interest us? I've rolled back to using obj-c associated objects, but would prefer swift implementation. The only thing I can think of is wrapping the objects in a wrapper with has it as weak property, maybe. I will probably try this idea. Thanks

Comment: In general, you should never assume that the `hashValue`s of two different values (defining "different" as `!=`) can never conflict. The `Hashable` axiom only states that two equal values must have the same hash value – the inverse is not necessarily true. Even if the `hashValue`s for `ObjectIdentifier` never happen to collide, this is an implementation detail and not something you should ever rely on.

Comment: A `Weak<T>` wrapper (or similar) would work, but you'd have to start thinking about how/when you'd garbage collect the weak values that are now `nil`. Again, I would highly recommend sticking with Obj-C associated objects that does this all for you :) Note that you classes don't even need to inherit from `NSObject` to take advantage of being able to have associated objects.

Comment: @Hamish as long as ObjectIdentifier hashValue = dec(memoryAddress) I believe we should be good :)

Comment: Yeah, weak is probably the best.

Comment: "*as long as ObjectIdentifier hashValue = dec(memoryAddress)*" – my point is that you *cannot* rely on this. In Swift 4.2, hash values get mixed with a per-execution seed and are fed through a Sip Hasher, so your assumption will no longer be true.

Comment: I'm currently using objc API, but then again, you have to manage keys, which in case of ObjC API should be pointers. Which leads to some funny code, provided you'd like to accept keys as Strings @Hamish :)

Comment: "*In Swift 4.2, hash values...*" - Interesting. Well, if string representation of ObjectIdentifier still returns hex memory address - this method can still be used. Thanks for the chat @Hamish :)

Comment: If you want the ability to use strings as keys, why not just associate a single `[String: Any]` dictionary value to the given object (using Obj-C associated objects), and use this to hold the key-value pairs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174413/discussion-between-dannie-p-and-hamish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ObjectIdentifiers (memory addresses) can indeed be re-used, which is proved by this simple snippet

```
class C {}

print(ObjectIdentifier(C()))
print(ObjectIdentifier(C()))
```

Probably the best way to know when the object is de-allocated is to poll a weak variable:

```
class C {}

var o: C? = C()
weak var weakO = o 
print("weakO == nil \(weakO == nil)")
o = nil
print("weakO == nil \(weakO == nil)")
```

Or, to have it more convenient, this way both object id and knowledge of whether the object is still around can be tracked:

```
class C {}

class ObjectWrapper {
    weak var object: AnyObject?
    var hash: Int

    init(_ object: AnyObject) {
        self.object = object
        hash = ObjectIdentifier(object).hashValue
    }
}

var obj1: C? = C()
let wrapper1 = ObjectWrapper(obj1!)
obj1 = nil

var obj2: C? = C()
let wrapper2 = ObjectWrapper(obj2!)

print("obj1 == nil: \(wrapper1.object == nil), hash: \(wrapper1.hash)")
print("obj2 == nil: \(wrapper2.object == nil), hash: \(wrapper2.hash)")
```